# Background image carousel with Bootstrap v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm still pretty new to coding, so I apologize if this is an easy fix. I'm using Ruby on Rails with the Bootstrap Gem.

I'm trying to set up a home page on my website that features an info box and sign up/sign in box with a background that is a three image carousel.

I've got the boxes set up with divs, but I can't get the images to fit the background. I'd like to have the images fade in, one after the other, but I'm stumped - any guides I've found so far are for earlier bootstrap versions.

Here is what I have currently.

```
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="position:relative;">
       <!-- Indicators -->
       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
       </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="sample.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="sample1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="sample2.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: please show `javascript` for carousel.

Comment: I haven't needed to implement any js, my guess because I've got a bootstrap gem installed? I'm running this with RoR.

Comment: I guess you are missing the `data-ride="carousel"` attribute in the `div#myCarousel`.